# Django html table - how to specify/locate a certain cell?

Tags: python, html, css, django

new to django and everything. I'm trying to figure out how to specify or locate a certain cell in a html table.

I would like to change the background color of certain cells if certain conditions are met based on the generated grid. I've registered a simple_tag, and I would like to be able to tell it which cell to change.

For example, if value of row 3, column 4 == x, then apply red background; or find cell of row 2, column 5, etc.
How do I address it?

Here's a simplified version of what I've done so far:

from views.py:

```
list1 = [a,b,c,d,e,f]    # this is basically what the table (grid) looks like
list2 = [b,c,a,d,f,e]
list3 = [f,a,e,d,c,b]
list4 = [c,d,a,b,f,e]
list5 = [d,e,b,a,f,c]
list6 = [e,b,a,c,d,f]
grid = [list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6]
result1 = [0, 1, 2]
result2 = [4, 5]
results = [result1, result2]
```

.html

```
{% for var in grid %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class='{% bg_color var.0 %}'>{{ var.0 }}</td>
            <td class='{% bg_color var.1 %}'>{{ var.1 }}</td>
            <td class='{% bg_color var.2 %}'>{{ var.2 }}</td>
            <td class='{% bg_color var.3 %}'>{{ var.3 }}</td>
            <td class='{% bg_color var.4 %}'>{{ var.4 }}</td>
            <td class='{% bg_color var.5 %}'>{{ var.5 }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
{% endfor %}
```

I would like every row's and column's to be colored according to the index numbers indicated in results. Result1 = red, result2 = yellow. If they overlap, then an overlapped color of red and yellow.
So color-wise it should be:

```
row1 : [red,        red,        red,        red,    red_yellow, red_yellow]    
row2 : [red,        red,        red,        red,    red_yellow, red_yellow]  
row3 : [red,        red,        red,        red,    red_yellow, red_yellow] 
row4 : [red,        red,        red,        none,   yellow,     yellow]  
row5 : [red_yellow, red_yellow, red_yellow, yellow, yellow,     yellow] 
row6 : [red_yellow, red_yellow, red_yellow, yellow, yellow,     yellow]
```

.css

```
    .red {
        background-color: red;
    }
    
    .yellow {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    .red_yellow {
        background-color: linear-gradient(rgba(220,0,0,0.5), rgba(220,0,0,0.5)),
linear-gradient(yellow, yellow);      
    }
```

filter_tag.py   ---i don't know what to do yet

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def bg_color(context, val):
    results = context['results']  
    if val in results[0]:   # here starts the problem
        return 'red'
    if val in result[1]:
        return 'yellow'
    if val in result[0] and val in result[1]:
        return 'red_yellow'
    else:
        return None
```

My problem now is by evaluating val, the table are colored based on the values in the cell but not the position of the cell. Also, there are overlapping issues with the css.

Is there a way I can specify cells by the index numbers of the rows and columns?
Or this is just not the right approach for it? If not, what would be appropriate?
I've only learned python so far so that would be the preferred language.

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can! If you use a **grid** you can specify where you want to place things. You would need to utilize a **grid display** and then create a **grid template**. From there assign parts of the grid to things you want to occupy the part of the grid. I also recommend looking at *flexboxfroggy.com* to get a better grasp on how to further manipulate the positions. In order to specify what part of the grid you want something to occupy you would need to manipulate the **grid template columns** as well as the **grid template rows**. Once you made the necessary changes you can put assign parts of the grid to a certain item using **grid template areas**. Note that I made a 3 x 5 grid and then replicated that grid's layout in my grid area template. The "." in the template means that the cell is empty.

**Example:**

```
 #main{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows:250px 70px 70px 200px;
    grid-template-areas: 
    ". A ."
    ". B ."
    ". C ."
    ". D ."
    ;
}
#A{
    grid-area: A;
}
#B{
    grid-area: B;
    }
#C{
    grid-area: C;
}
#D{
    grid-area:D;

}
```

Comment: Thank you! The froggy website looks quite fun! See that they have grid garden too. I'll check it out for sure.

Comment: Hi again, I've looked into the grid thing a bit more, it seems what i need to locate cells. I'm still not quite clear on how to make it do what I want. Would you mind clarifying a bit more about how to **assign parts of the grid to things you want to occupy the part of the grid** dynamically?

Comment: done! let me know if you need any further clarification.